# How to Register Script in response extensions?

Tags: c#, ajax

I have  an HttpResponseExtensions class the extends the functionality of HttpResponse. I want to add a method the redirect user in AJAX Requests. so here is my method the do the check :

```
    public static void RedirectUser(this HttpResponse response, string url)
    {
        if (response.IsRequestBeingRedirecting())
            return;
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context != null)
        {
            context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
        if (context != null && context.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            context.Items["IsRedirecting"] = true;
            RegisterRedirectScript(response,url);
        }
        else
        {
            response.Redirect(url, false);
        }
    }
```

And here is implementation for the RegisterRedirectScript  method

```
    public static void RegisterRedirectScript(this HttpResponse response, string url)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context != null)
        {
            context.Response.Write(string.Format("<script                       type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = '{0}';</script>", url));
        }
    }
```

I am calling RedirectUser when session is invalidated. However if the request is ajax one : I receive this following error :

```
The Message recived from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are the response is modified calls to response.write(), response details , HttpModule, OR server trace is enabled. Error detailes next to : window.locat.
```

I know I can register a script by using radAjaxManager, ClientScriptManager or the ScriptManager. But How Can I do it for the HttpResponse Class?

Any Help is appreciated.